# Passing Datagrid Selection to RelayCommand when pressing a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, mvvm-light

I'm new to C#, WPF and MVVM and trying to figure out how to solve the following problem:
I have a Datagrid which is bound to an ObservableCollection. This ObservableCollection consists of a struct, which has multiple fields, one of those fields is a string called clientName. I have a button which raises a command. This command requires the clientName to execute properly.

I solved this by using a property which is bound to the (first) selected item of the datagrid. By pressing the button, the command is fired without passing the clientName directly to the command. Instead it simply uses the selection property I made.

How can I pass the datagrids current selection to the command (when pressing the button) without using a property to store the selected item?

Comment: Can you show some of your code with how you currently have things setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your `Button`:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=yourDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

or, directly bound to the `clientName`-property of the `SelectedItem`

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=yourDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.clientName}"
```

Your Command could look like:

```
YourCommand = new RelayCommand<ParameterType>(CommandExecMethod);
```

```
private void CommandExecMethod(ParameterType arg)
{  
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Possibly change `Path` to `SelectedItem.ClientName` (assuming @fortyseveneleven has a property to expose the name.